# Issue on image data processing with iOS 11

Tags: objective-c, image-processing, ios11

i really need your help today ! I'm debugging an old objective-c app created by another dev and there's a new bug that only appear on iOS 11.
The bug come's from a image processing function used when trying to create a "Scratch View", similar to this one -> https://github.com/joehour/ScratchCard
But, since iOS 11, the function doesn't work anymore, in the code above i've got an error on `[Unknown process name] CGImageMaskCreate: invalid image provider: NULL.` <-- the variable CGDataProviderRef dataProvider is not created (null)

```
// Method to change the view which will be scratched
- (void)setHideView:(UIView *)hideView
{
CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(hideView.bounds.size, NO, 0);
[hideView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
hideView.layer.contentsScale = scale;
_hideImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext().CGImage;
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

size_t imageWidth = CGImageGetWidth(_hideImage);
size_t imageHeight = CGImageGetHeight(_hideImage);

CFMutableDataRef pixels = CFDataCreateMutable(NULL, imageWidth * imageHeight);
_contextMask = CGBitmapContextCreate(CFDataGetMutableBytePtr(pixels), imageWidth, imageHeight , 8, imageWidth, colorspace, kCGImageAlphaNone);
CGDataProviderRef dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(pixels);
CFRelease(pixels);

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(_contextMask, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
CGContextFillRect(_contextMask, self.frame);

CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(_contextMask, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
CGContextSetLineWidth(_contextMask, _sizeBrush);
CGContextSetLineCap(_contextMask, kCGLineCapRound);

CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(imageWidth, imageHeight, 8, 8, imageWidth, dataProvider, nil, NO);
_scratchImage = CGImageCreateWithMask(_hideImage, mask);
CGDataProviderRelease(dataProvider);

CGImageRelease(mask);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
}
```

I'm not an expert of this function of image processing and i'm really lost for debugging this part... 
Does anyone know why this function doesn't work anymore in iOS 11 ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

iOS 11 stopped handling `CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(null)` therefore you **will need** to set the length of `pixels`.

Something like:

```
...
CFMutableDataRef pixels = CFDataCreateMutable(NULL, imageWidth * imageHeight);
CFDataSetLength(pixels, imageWidth * imageHeight); // this is the line you're missing for iOS11+
_contextMask = ...
...
```